# C++ Main thread notifying threads notifying main thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, conditional-statements

Well I need help. I'm trying to do something a bit specific and my lack of multithreading skills is killing me.

Basically my main program/thread needs to manage a number of "channels" that have to be run a number of times. Since those runs are independant each channel includes a thread in which they are performed.

So the main thread has to wait for all channels (threads) to finish their run to be able to launch the next one.
And all channels have to wait for a notification from the main thread that they can run.

Below is how I did it - sorry it's a bit long!

```
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>

std::mutex              g_lockprint;
std::mutex              g_lockbatch;
std::condition_variable g_nextbatch;
std::mutex              g_lockready;
std::condition_variable g_ready;

int global_id = 0;
int nbChannels = 5;
std::atomic<int> nbChannelsLeftToEnd;

class Channel {

private:

    int _id;
    std::thread _th;
    std::atomic<bool> next_batch;
    std::atomic<bool> stop_th;

public:

    Channel() : _id(global_id++), _th(), next_batch(false), stop_th(false) {}

    void go_for_next_batch() { next_batch = true; }

    void start(int& start, int &end){
        _th = std::thread(&Channel::run, this, std::ref(start), std::ref(end));
    }

    void stop(){
        stop_th = true;
        _th.join();
    }

    void run(int& start, int& end){
        while (!stop_th){
            {
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(g_lockbatch);
                g_nextbatch.wait(locker, [&](){return (next_batch==true); });
            }

            // print a starting message
            {
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(g_lockprint);
                std::cout << "[channel " << _id << "]\trunning in [" << start << "," << end << "]" << std::endl;
            }

            // simulate work
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

            // update the number of channels left to run
            nbChannelsLeftToEnd--;
            g_ready.notify_one();
            next_batch = false;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    int end = 100;
    int batch = 10;
    int startBatch = 0;
    int endBatch = startBatch + batch;

    // declare some channels (threads)
    std::vector<Channel> channels(nbChannels);

    // start the threads
    for (auto& ch : channels) ch.start(startBatch, endBatch);

    while (endBatch<=end){
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(g_lockprint);
            std::cout << "[main]\trunning in [" << startBatch << "," << endBatch << "]" << std::endl;
        }
        nbChannelsLeftToEnd = nbChannels;
        for (auto& ch : channels) ch.go_for_next_batch();
        g_nextbatch.notify_all();

        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(g_lockready);
        g_ready.wait(locker, [&](){return (nbChannelsLeftToEnd == 0); });

        startBatch += batch;
        endBatch += batch;
    }

    for (auto& ch : channels) ch.stop();

    return 0;
}
```

But sometimes the program blocks, probably threads waiting on each other but I can't see why.
And in any case, joining the threads ("stop" method at the end of the main) makes my program run indefinitely, can't see why either.

**EDIT** : thanks to your comments and some research I managed to get a working program using a synchronization barrier so the main thread can wait for all other threads to finish the current batch before telling them to start the next one.
I reused the barrier code from someone here that was quoting [Anthony Wiiliams's book](https://www.manning.com/books/c-plus-plus-concurrency-in-action) - here's the **barrier**:

```
class barrier
{
    unsigned const count;
    std::atomic<unsigned> spaces;
    std::atomic<unsigned> generation;

public:
    explicit barrier(unsigned count_) :
        count(count_), spaces(count), generation(0) {}

    void wait()
    {
        unsigned const my_generation = generation;
        if (!--spaces)
        {
            spaces = count;
            ++generation;
        }
        else
        {
            while (generation == my_generation)
                std::this_thread::yield();
        }
    }
};
```

Here's the new **run** method for the Channel class using the barrier - notice the additional test on the "stop_th" flag. When the thread gets unblocked after the last batch and before being joined, it shouldn't run another batch, hence that test.

```
void run(int& start, int& end, barrier& b)
{
    while (!stop_th){
        // wait for next batch notification - use the next_batch flag to avoid
        // spurious wake-ups
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(g_lockbatch);
            g_nextbatch.wait(locker, [&](){return (next_batch==true); });
        }

        if (stop_th) return;

        // simulate work
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

        // wait for everyone to meet
        next_batch = false;
        b.wait();
    }
}
```

And finally here's the **main**:

```
int main()
{
    int end = 100;
    int batch = 10;
    int startBatch = 0;
    int endBatch = startBatch + batch;

    // declare a barrier where all threads will meet
    barrier b(nbChannels+1);

    // declare some channels (threads)
    std::vector<Channel> channels(nbChannels);

    // start the threads
    for (auto& ch : channels) ch.start(startBatch, endBatch, b);

    while (endBatch<=end){

        // notify the channels they can process one batch
        for (auto& ch : channels) ch.go_for_next_batch();
        g_nextbatch.notify_all();

        // wait until all threads have finished their batch
        b.wait();

        // prepare the next one
        startBatch += batch;
        endBatch += batch;
    }

    // all channels are blocked by the next_batch condition
    // so notify a next batch and join them
    for (auto& ch : channels) ch.stop();
    for (auto& ch : channels) ch.go_for_next_batch();
    g_nextbatch.notify_all();
    for (auto& ch : channels) ch.wait_until_stopped();

    return 0;
}
```

Again, thanks for all your comments / answers!!!

Comment: You should be able to connect up a debugger to the live process (e.g. `gdb <exe name> <pid>` on Linux) and list the current status of the threads. I've found this normally gives a good indication of what's causing the problem. I suspect you should try to stick to one mutex or only lock/unlock in strict sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my comment into an answer since I fixed the code in cpp.sh and it seems to complete now.

Regarding them not existing when calling stop. 
Notice that they may still be stuck waiting on the next batch lock. 
Consider adding a call to release them from their lock and have them check if they stopped after the locking step.

Separate the stop function into two functions, one you change the boolean and another where you wait.
Lets call the two functions stop and wait_until_stopped

Then add the following code to the main function.

Instead of

```
for (auto& ch : channels) ch.stop();
```

Use:

```
for (auto& ch : channels) ch.stop();

for (auto& ch : channels) ch.go_for_next_batch();

g_nextbatch.notify_all();

for (auto& ch : channels) ch.wait_until_stopped();
```

Comment: +1! indeed threads were waiting for the next batch, your solution works perfectly! well, at least when I get to that point, the program often freezes before that so there might be some issues left...

Comment: If you have a freeze in the program it is most likely a dead lock.
A race between the locks.
Attach a debugger and see who is waiting for who like @Component 10 suggested.